# Pandas: Copy values from one column when two other columns are unique pairs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to fill empty rows if there are rows where two columns are unique pairs.  If Col2 is A1, any rows where col2 is A1 and the customer is the same (i.e. Cust1), then combine all Col3 values where this is true and replace all rows with the combined result.

Essentially, I'm running a script to filter to certain rows, but the "Version" columns are empty. There are values for the "Version" columns in rows that don't meet the criteria, so I want to combine all the "Version" data where "Customer" and "Model" are a unique pair.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=2)

grouped = df.groupby('Model').agg({'Version1':','.join,'Version2':','.join})
```

Example table

```
Customer        Model        Version1       Version2
Cust1           A1           1, 2           5
Cust1           A1           3              6
Cust1           A1           NaN            NaN
Cust2           A2           1              3
Cust2           A1           2              NaN
Cust2           A2           NaN            4
```

End Result:

```
Customer        Model        Version1       Version2
Cust1           A1           1, 2, 3        5, 6
Cust1           A1           1, 2, 3        5, 6
Cust1           A1           1, 2, 3        5, 6
Cust2           A2           1              3, 4
Cust2           A1           2              NaN
Cust2           A2           1              3, 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own function to determine all of the unique versions within every Customer-Model grouping. Then use `transform` to broadcast the result back to every row of that group.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['Cust1']*3+['Cust2']*3,
                   'Model': ['A1']*3 + ['A2', 'A1', 'A2'],
                   'Version1': ['1, 2', '3', np.NaN, '1', '2', np.NaN],
                   'Version2': ['5', '6', np.NaN, '3', np.NaN, '4']})
```

#### Code:

```
def my_join(x):
    x = x.dropna()
    if x.empty:
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return ', '.join(np.unique(x.str.split(',\s?').sum()))

gp = df.groupby(['Customer', 'Model'])
for col in ['Version1', 'Version2']:
    df[col] = gp[col].transform(my_join)
```

#### Output:

```
  Customer Model Version1 Version2
0    Cust1    A1  1, 2, 3     5, 6
1    Cust1    A1  1, 2, 3     5, 6
2    Cust1    A1  1, 2, 3     5, 6
3    Cust2    A2        1     3, 4
4    Cust2    A1        2      NaN   
5    Cust2    A2        1     3, 4
```

This will take care of cases where values are repeated within different fields: `'1, 2'` and `'1, 3'` in Version1 will still return `'1, 2, 3'` as your output:

---

It appears that `.transform(str.join)` has issues when there are null grouping keys. So we can mask those first to fix the `ValueError`:

```
m = df[['Customer', 'Model']].notnull().all(1)

gp = df[m].groupby(['Customer', 'Model'])
for col in ['Version1', 'Version2']:
    df.loc[m, col] = gp[col].transform(my_join)
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I'm getting an error because the lengths aren't the same.  I'm not sure why.  Here's the error: "'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 142 elements, new values have 180 elements"

Comment: @jhnkly What is the output of `df[['Customer', 'Model']].isnull().sum()`

Comment: Customer: 0; Model: 38

Comment: Okay, see my update, that should solve the problem. You won't be able to join the fields for those rows since you are missing one of the grouping keys.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you so much.  The mask makes sense because there isn't always a model number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work.
I used your table as a starting point and I get your expected outcome.

```
import pandas as pd
example = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='example')
core = example[['Customer','Model']].drop_duplicates()
for index, row in core.iterrows():
    filtered_example = example[(example['Customer'] == row['Customer'])
                               & (example['Model'] == row['Model'])]
    list_v1 = list(filtered_example['Version1'].drop_duplicates().dropna())
    example.at[(example['Customer'] == row['Customer'])
                 & (example['Model'] == row['Model']),'Version1'] = str(list_v1)
    list_v2 = list(filtered_example['Version2'].drop_duplicates().dropna())
    example.at[(example['Customer'] == row['Customer'])
                 & (example['Model'] == row['Model']),'Version2'] = str(list_v2)
print(example)
```

I hope it helps.
BR

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby and transform,

```
df[['Version1','Version2']] = df.groupby(['Customer','Model']).transform(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()))

    Customer    Model   Version1    Version2
0   Cust1       A1      1, 2, 3     5, 6
1   Cust1       A1      1, 2, 3     5, 6
2   Cust1       A1      1, 2, 3     5, 6
3   Cust2       A2      1           3, 4
4   Cust2       A1      2   
5   Cust2       A2      1           3, 4
```